# Mask a sphere with text

Tags: opengl

I want to use openGL to draw a hollow sphere. The material properties of sphere is different for front and back surfaces. Now I want to mask the sphere with a text, so that the inner surface becomes visible from the text area. I am not able to understand how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the sphere twice:

1. `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)`, then draw sphere.  This will put all back-facing triangles in the depth and color buffers.
2. `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`, bind text texture, enable alpha test, draw sphere.  Where the alpha test fails the color buffer won't be updated and you'll be able to "see through" to the inside of the sphere.